# Android string array resource item substitution

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources

I had a problem where I needed to map some keys received from a website to image id's in my android app.

The solution I initally came up with was to use switch statements like so:

```
switch (weather_type) {
    case "cloudy":
        return R.drawable.cloudy;
    case "rainy":
        return R.drawable.rainy;

    // etc
}
```

This is good and works great, but I was thinking if there was a way to store this information in XML and have it available at runtime. I was thinking something like a map in XML that lets me map the names to the actual resource, but since I'm still learning android, I'm not sure exactly how to go about doing this.

My plan then involved creating a `string-array` in xml to retrieve the values.

```
<string-array name="icon_map">
    <item>cloudy:@mipmap/cloudy</item>
    <item>rainy:@mipmap/rain</item>
</string-array>
```

In Java:

```
String []array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.icon_map);
Log.i(TAG, array[0]);
```

Results in

`1798-1798/com.practice.smac89.webstuff I/MainActivity cloudy:@mipmap/cloudy`

When I was typing this in Android Studio, it was showing the actual images when I hover my mouse over the resources. So I was hoping that when I get this in the activity class, it would have been converted to the actual Id, but it wasn't.

### TL;DR

Is there a way to store a mapping in xml where the value is a resource id and get the actual integer id in java?
I was hoping for

`1798-1798/com.practice.smac89.webstuff I/MainActivity cloudy:1231243`

Comment: I think your original idea sounds like the best option, create a `HashMap<String, Integer>`, and have a method that populates it once when your app starts up.

Answer (score 1):

```
TypedArray ar = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.my_array);
int len = ar.length();
int[] resIds = new int[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    resIds[i] = ar.getResourceId(i, 0);
ar.recycle();
// Do stuff with resolved reference array, resIds[]...
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    Log.v (TAG, "Res Id " + i + " is " + Integer.toHexString(resIds[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you can get what you want by using string array and integer array at the same time, like below, in XML you define two arrays.

```
<string-array name="name_array">
    <item>cloudy</item>
    <item>rainy</item>
</string-array>

<array name="icon_array">
    <item>@mipmap/cloudy</item>
    <item>@mipmap/rain</item>
</array>
```

In Java, you can do

```
String [] nameArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name_array);

int[] iconArray = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.icon_array);

for(int i=0; i<nameArray.length; i++){

      if(nameArray[i].equals(weather_type)){

           return iconArray[i])
      }    
}
```

Here is my sample of string array and drawable array.

```
<string-array name="settings_titles">

<item>@string/TITLE_SERVICES</item>

<item>@string/TITLE_USERACCOUNTS</item>

<item>@string/TITLE_ABOUT</item>

</string-array>


<array name="settings_icons">

<item>@drawable/ic_android_services</item>

<item>@drawable/ic_android_users</item>

<item>@drawable/ic_android_about</item>

</array>
```

and you also can use TypedArray to access the resource. like

```
final TypedArray mTitles = getResources().obtainTypedArray(titlesId);
```

Comment: my bad, the iconArray is not a String Array, should be a IntArray.